# Obtaining configured properties from Springs

Tags: spring

I am trying to obtain properties' values configured in Springs context with Environment bean (like in [spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and context:property-placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542506/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-and-contextproperty-placeholder) checked answer).

```
public class SpringsPropertiesProvider implements IPropertiesProvider {
    @Autowired Environment envinronment;

    @Override
    public String getProperty(String key) {
        return envinronment.getProperty(key);
    }

}
```

This class is registered with following xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:myproject/example.properties" />
<context:annotation-config />
<bean class="myproject.SpringsPropertiesProvider" id="springsPropertiesProvider"/>
```

But SpringsPropertiesProvider.getProperty method does not return values configured within example.properties file.

What I am doing wrong and how can I get dynamic access to properties configured by placeholderconfigurer?

PS.
During environment.getPropert(key) call debugging shows that org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver has only two entries in its propertySources field ([systemProperties,systemEnvironment]) and both entries does not contain any keys defined within example.properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:myproject/example.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

If the project does not startup then that means spring was not able to locate the properties file. 
Speaking of which, what does your project structure look like?

**Update:**

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21106326/2504224) explains why this is not working

Comment: Geoand thank you. I checked this almost as you suggested - by making file path incorrect and context loading consequently was failed - so original path setting was correct.

Comment: What happens if you inject a property with @Value("${nameOfProperty})?

Comment: It seems that the Environment objects does not contain user specified properties. 

Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21106326/2504224

Comment: Seems that the answer in this link explains why it is not working. But I  still need to find the way to get configured properties without direct passing references to props. files. Please edit your answer with reference to this link.