# Setting up Spring 4.1 profile environment using YAML instead of Properties and @Profile

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to set up my profiles using YAML configuration files. Rather than having different `@Configuration` classes annotated with `@Profile` for different ones (or even a same `@Configuration` class with different annotated `@Beans`), i would like to have one `@Configuration` class using Placeholder with YAML configuration file.

Taking a look at [Spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml), [YamlPropertiesFactoryBean javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.html) and [this Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303758/how-to-use-yamlpropertiesfactorybean-to-load-yaml-files-using-spring-framework-4/28829727#28829727), i've came up with the following code:

A simple YAML file: `application-default-config.yml`

```
foo: myFoo
```

A `@Configuration` file:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ymlProperties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer =
        new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("config/application-${spring.profiles.active:default}-config.yml"));
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());

    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
  }

  @Value("${foo}")
  private String fooValue;

  @Bean
  public String fooValue() {
    return fooValue;
  }
}
```

A test file:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfig.class)
public class ApplicationConfigTest {    

  @Autowired
  Environment environment;

  @Autowired
  String fooValue;

  @Test
  public void testFooViaEnvironment() {
    Assert.assertEquals("myFoo", environment.getProperty("foo"));
  }

  @Test
  public void testFooViaWiredValue() {
    Assert.assertEquals("myFoo", fooValue);
  }
}
```

And, finally, a main file:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

    ctx.register(ApplicationConfig.class);

    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("config/application-${spring.profiles.active:default}-config.yml"));

    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = ctx.getEnvironment();
    environment.getPropertySources()
        .addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("custom", yaml.getObject()));

    ctx.refresh();

    String fooViaWiredValue = (String) ctx.getBean("fooValue");

    System.out.println(String.format("fooViaEnvironment=%s", environment.getProperty("foo")));

    System.out.println(String.format("fooViaWiredValue=%s", fooViaWiredValue));

  }
}
```

I've noticed that in my test class, i can access the 'foo' property via `@Value` annotation but not via `Environment`.
As well explained in some Stackoverflow topics like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100729/propertysourcesplaceholderconfigurer-not-registering-with-environment-in-a-sprin/21106326#21106326) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169834/spring-3-1-environment-does-not-work-with-user-property-files/14170198#14170198), annotating a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as a `@Bean` is not enough to tight it with the `Environment`. It is necessary to do it programmatically as i did in `Application` class. In contrast, annotated `@Value`s are wired accordingly.

My questions are, in fact, about best practices working with Spring.
I would prefer using `Environment` rather than `@Value` annotation.
Is there any way to load my YAML configuration files into Spring application context inside a test environment without needing to do it programmatically as i did in `Application` class ?

Is there any reason i should prefer using `@Value` (or any other profile configuration) over `Environment` +  YAML configuration files ? As i said, i would like to have a unique `@Bean` using placeholders rather than multiples `@Bean`s annotated with `@Profile`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [SPR](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8539) where Chris Beams states why PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer should not be registered automatically by Spring and why one should prefer user `Environment` over `@value`.

In addition, on Spring reference documentation, the [Spring Testing Annotation section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations) shows how to use `ApplicationContextInitializer`, which could be used to setup `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean` properly.